# Is there any way to group CSS elements/selectors?

Tags: html, css, formatting

Currently I have something like:

```
.class1 p {
    blablabla
}

.class1 h1 {
    blaaa
}

.class1 a {
    bla bla bla
}
```

Is there any way I can compress this down even moer to make it look neater? I end up with 40 or so entries for .class1 which is an eyesore.

edit: I mean't to keep them all different (e.g. h1 is black and p is red), but compress the space it takes down when written up to make it look more simple.

tl;dr group selectors?

Comment: There are3 no “CSS elements”. CSS selectors can be grouped as defined in CSS specifications. What you are asking looks like a request for a tool to make CSS code “neater”, i.e. please your eye and mind, which is highly subjective. And what you *can* do technically depends heavily on the blablabla. You have not presented any *concrete* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at a CSS preprocessor such as [Less](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) that allows you to use nesting. For example in your `.less` file it would look like:

```
.class {
    p {
        ....
    }

    h1 {
        ....
    }

    a {
        ....
    }
}
```

and still compile into exactly your code example in the `.css` file. However if you're going down this route make sure that you don't start nesting too deep as that would create really specific selectors.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the compiled CSS will look no different to the original code. A prep-processor only make the CSS easier to **write**.

Comment: Another nice and easy feature of CSS preprocessors are variables. Instead of repeating the same color everywhere you can define it once (e.g. `@brand-color: #f99;`) and use that (e.g. `color: @brand-color;`)

Comment: @Paulie_D good point! tried to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Use `,` to group selection like this:

```
.class1 p, .class1 h1, .class1 a{
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't explaining what I meant properly. I mean't to keep them all different (e.g. h1 is black and p is red), but compress the space it takes down when written up to make it look more simple.

Comment: use less or sass as @ckuijjer answered for you then